# what is 'and!' in the validation computation expression with FsToolkit.ErrorHandling, in F#

Tags: f#, computation-expression

when using FsToolkit.ErrorHandling and looking at this example:

```
testCase "Happy Path Result" <| fun () ->
        let actual : Validation<int, string> = validation {
            let! a = Ok 3
            and! b = Ok 2
            and! c = Ok 1
            return a + b - c
        }
```

what is the meaning of *and!*? it looks like *let!* gets mapped to Result.bind, but I don't see a different behavior between *let!* and *and!*

as far as I can see, it looks like replacing *and!* with *let!* keeps the same behavior.

I've just started dabbling in computation expressions and things are starting to make sense, although I don't really understand why we have different nomenclature between the F# keywords like let and the actual functions like bind so it's adding a layer of confusion. So the answer to this may be obvious :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the new support for ["applicative computation expressions"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/whats-new/fsharp-50#applicative-computation-expressions) introduced in F# 5.0.

The difference between `let!` and `and!` is that `let!` allows a value to depend on a prior result, while `and!` does not. This is useful for cases where your computation is an [applicative](https://adit.io/posts/2013-04-17-functors,_applicatives,_and_monads_in_pictures.html), but not a full monad, or when you want to perform independent steps in a computation in parallel.

For example, with `let!` you could write this:

```
let! a = Ok 3
let! b = Ok (2 * a)   // Allowed: value of b depends on a
```

But you can't write this:

```
let! a = Ok 3
and! b = Ok (2 * a)   // Not allowed: value of b depends on a
```